# Search on Table JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am new to JQuery and I am making an html page where the user can search for a Book ID once the search button is clicked. The problem is, the search button is not responding. Here's my code.

Here's the php file:

```
<?php


require("dbconnect.php");


$sql = "select * from tbl_books";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());




/** table **/

 echo "<table border='1'
 cellpadding='5'>";

 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<th>Name</th>";
 echo "<th>Category</th>";
 echo "<th>Author</th>";

 echo "</tr>";


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$id = $row['bid'];
$bname=$row['bname'];
$category=$row['category'];
$author=$row['author'];



echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>$bname</td>";
echo "<td>$category</td>";
echo "<td>$author</td>";

}
?>
```

Html

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <header>

    <title>
    Main Page
    </title>



       <script type="text/javascript"
        src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>

  <script>

$(function() {
        $.post("bookoramaBookDisplay.php",

               function(data){
                $("#display").html(data); 
        });
    });

</script>

 <script>

$(function() {
    $("#btnsearch").click(function() {

        var search=$("#txtsearch").val();

        $.post("bookoramaBookDisplay.php",
            {txtsearch:search},
               function(data){
                $("#display").html(data);

        });
    });

});

</script>


</header>



  <body>
    <div id = "table2">


        <div id = "taas">

        <input type="text"
               name = "txtsearch_name"
               id = "txtsearch"
               placeholder="Search Book">

        <input type="button"
               value="Search"
               id = "btnsearch">
        </div>

        <div id = "baba">


            <div id = "display">

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

A little help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: show your html source code.

Comment: Try console.log(data) to your response and see what response come from backend.

Comment: are you sure your query $result is not empty?.

Comment: try your query like this  mysql_query("select * from tbl_books").

Comment: In  your PHP code close the TR tag inside the loop and after the loop close the table tag.

Comment: Did you get book details without search?

Comment: well, i can see the book details without searching for it. but what i want to happen is that if i put 1 on the search box, a specific book should be displayed

Comment: Then where is your search query?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Main Page
</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type:  'POST',
            cache:  false ,
            url: "bookoramaBookDisplay.php",
            success: function(rmsg){
                $("#display").html(rmsg);
            }
        });
        $("#btnsearch").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type:  'POST',
                cache:  false ,
                url: "bookoramaBookDisplay.php",
                data: {txtsearch:search},
                success: function(rmsg){
                $("#display").html(rmsg);
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
</head>
  <body>
 <div id = "table2">
    <div id = "taas">
    <input type="text" name = "txtsearch_name" id = "txtsearch" placeholder="Search Book">
    <input type="button" value="Search" id = "btnsearch">
    </div>

    <div id = "baba">
    <div id = "display">
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
require("dbconnect.php");



  $where='';
if($_POST[txtsearch]){
   $where = "WHERE `bid`='".$_POST[txtsearch]."'";
}
$sql = "select * from tbl_books $where";


$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or die(mysql_error());




/** table **/

 echo "<table border='1'
 cellpadding='5'>";

 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<th>Name</th>";
 echo "<th>Category</th>";
 echo "<th>Author</th>";

 echo "</tr>";


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$id = $row['bid'];
$bname=$row['bname'];
$category=$row['category'];
$author=$row['author'];



echo "<tr><td>".$bname."</td><td>".$category."</td><td>".$author."</td></tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: button is still not responsive.

Comment: can you post complete html and jquery page. So that I will find error.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be

```
$where='';
if($_POST[txtsearch]){
   $where = "WHERE `bid`='".$_POST[txtsearch]."'";
}
$sql = "select * from tbl_books $where";
```